# Can you override Godot's default physics and code your own custom physics?

Tags: godot

I have been using Godot for a while now(for at least 4 months) and now I decided to take a huge leap in my 3D game making. I mean I like Godot's ready-made physics a lot and it is almost perfect but I wanna code my own custom physics. I wanna alter ray-tracing to a way I like better and other physics aspects(find it hard to explain :) ) and have better control over the physics in my game for every prop and stuff. I just wanna know whether I can disable ready-made Godot physics.

Comment: You can't disable godot's physics engine from script or the editor. You can write your own entire physics system from script and never touch godot's physics objects. You can override `RigidBody._integrate_forces()` and use your own logic. You can bypass nodes and work with PhysicsServer. Lastly, you can write your own godot physics server module in c++. I'd recommend starting with overriding [integrate forces](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_rigidbody.html#class-rigidbody-method-integrate-forces).

Comment: hey man, thanks a lot. that really helped.